# Summation of a list of numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, asymptote, calculations

The next code gives : `1 1.2 3`
But `1 2.2 5.2` is expected. What is wrong ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\xdef\Sum{0}
\foreach \i in {1,1.2,3} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Sum{\Sum+\i}
    \Sum\ }

\end{document}
```

Comment: The body of a `\foreach` statement is carried out in a new group. See the `pgf` manual for more information.

Comment: Pkg `pgfplots` provides a [non-grouping variant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640492).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the definition of the macro `\Sum` is local to the group. At the next iteration, its content is forgotten and only the first global definition with `\xdef` is kept. I don't know much about it though.

Here is a working example (but probably not the best way to do it).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\xdef\Sum{0}
\foreach \i in {1,1.2,3} {
    \xdef\Sum{\Sum+\i}
    \pgfmathparse{\Sum}\pgfmathresult\ }

\end{document}
```

The output is as expected: `1.0 2.2 5.2`

Comment: '\xdef\ is equivalent to '\global\edef', so it expands the second argument (the substitution text) once and globally binds it to the first argument (the command sequence).

Answer (score 5):

With `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\sumlist{ m }
 {
  \tarass_sum_list:n { #1 }
 }

\fp_new:N \l__tarass_partial_sum_fp

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tarass_sum_list:n #1
 {
  \fp_zero:N \l__tarass_partial_sum_fp
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \fp_add:Nn \l__tarass_partial_sum_fp { ##1 }
    $\fp_use:N \l__tarass_partial_sum_fp$
    \ %
   }
   \unskip % remove the last space
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sumlist{1,1.2,3}

\sumlist{1,-1.2,3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version which will print the sum exactly with the number of necessary digits.

Hmm... that was not what was asked.Sorry.

Ok, so I update the code to do the printing of partial sums which was asked for. As has been pointed out the issue with `\foreach` is one of local groups limiting the scope. The `\xintFor` loop from `xinttools` does not have this issue. And thus I use it here. While I am at it I use the arithmetics of `xintfrac` package. But the `\xintFor` loop could have been used with `pgfmath` as math engine.

Then, the second element which I earlier had focused on is the printing of a decimal number with exactly the number of digits needed. Notice that the macros here are compatible with arbitrarily long numbers.

> [image: partial sums]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xintfrac}
\usepackage{xinttools}

% Let's first do the partial sums as fixed point numbers.
% We hardcode \Sum macro to hold the partial sums
\newcommand\TarassSumList [1]{\def\Sum{0}\xintFor ##1 in {#1}\do
       {\oodef\Sum{\xintAdd{\Sum}{##1}}%
        \xintRound{4}{\Sum}%
        \xintifForLast{}{, }}}

% let's now do it again but printing with the number of necessary
% digits:

% 
% We abstract some command from code below (an expandable version
% should be added to xint package)

\makeatletter
\def\ReduceDec@helper #1[#2]{#2}% duplicate of \sumlist@helper
\newcommand\ReduceDec [1]{%
         \oodef\ReduceDec@X {\xintREZ{#1}}%
         \oodef\ReduceDec@N {\expandafter\ReduceDec@helper\ReduceDec@X }%
         \ifnum\ReduceDec@N<\z@
            \oodef\ReduceDecResult{\xintTrunc {-\ReduceDec@N}{\ReduceDec@X}}%
         \else
            \oodef\ReduceDecResult{\xintNum \ReduceDec@X}%
         \fi }
\makeatother

\newcommand\TarassSumListB [1]{\def\Sum{0}\xintFor ##1 in {#1}\do
       {\oodef\Sum{\xintAdd{\Sum}{##1}}%
        \ReduceDec{\Sum}\let\Sum\ReduceDecResult
         \Sum
        \xintifForLast{}{, }}}

% earlier answer which concentrated on the printing of decimal number with
% exactly the needed number of digits.

% sum decimal numbers, and print the result with exactly as
% many digits as necessary after the decimal mark

% It would be  quite easier to print a truncation or rounding to a
% given number of digits after decimal mark (\xintTrunc or \xintRound
% and the whole thing would be completely expandable)

% To avoid scaring people, I did not make this more challenging version
% expandable...

% And it is to be used only for decimal numbers or scientific number on
% input, no fractions like 3/7.

\makeatletter
\def\sumlist@helper #1[#2]{#2}% there should be a macro in xintfrac for that
\newcommand\sumlist [1]{%
         \oodef\sumlist@S {\xintREZ{\xintSum{\xintCSVtoList {#1}}}}%
         \oodef\sumlist@N {\expandafter\sumlist@helper\sumlist@S }%
         \ifnum\sumlist@N<\z@
            \xintTrunc {-\sumlist@N}{\sumlist@S}%
         \else
            \xintNum \sumlist@S
         \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

Fixed point numbers (4 decimal digits):

\TarassSumList{1,1.2,3}

\TarassSumList{1,-1.2,3}

\TarassSumList {1.23, 3.31, -0.54}

\TarassSumList {1.234, 5.6789, 3.211768, -17.28929}

\TarassSumList {1.234, 5.6789, 3.211768, -17.28929, 13.004622}

\TarassSumList {1.23e-3, 3.25e-3, 17.123e-4}

Numbers with as many digits as necessary:

\TarassSumListB{1,1.2,3}

\TarassSumListB{1,-1.2,3}

\TarassSumListB {1.23, 3.31, -0.54}

\TarassSumListB {1.234, 5.6789, 3.211768, -17.28929}

\TarassSumListB {1.234, 5.6789, 3.211768, -17.28929, 13.004622}

\TarassSumListB {1.23e-3, 3.25e-3, 17.123e-4}


% \sumlist{1,1.2,3}

% \sumlist{1,-1.2,3}

% \sumlist {1.23, 3.31, -0.54}

% \sumlist {1.234, 5.6789, 3.211768, -17.28929}

% \sumlist {1.234, 5.6789, 3.211768, -17.28929, 13.004622}

% \sumlist {1.23e-3, 3.25e-3, 17.123e-4}

% \sumlist {100, 200}

\end{document}
```

> [image: sum list of decimal numbers]

Answer (score 1):

Ti*k*z groups the loop body of `\foreach`, making macro definitions local. Package `pgfplots` provides a non-grouping variant:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\Sum{0}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1,1.2,3} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Sum{\Sum+\i}
    \Sum\ }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just practice with [Asymptote](http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/) using a built-in `sum(a)` function to calculate the sum of all elements of a given array of real number `a`.

[image]

```
real[] a={1,1.2,-5};
write(a);

real T=sum(a);
write("The sum of all elements is");
write(T);
```