# Plotting the sum of a function in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I am trying to plot a function that is the sum of another function based on the parameter.

A famous example of this is the "sum of squares", however the functions I really want to do this do not have an explicit formula.

The following example shows the result I would like to get and a method how I would like to have it, which is obviously not giving the correct result.

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
  % Explicit formula
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{explicit_sum}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{(#1*(#1-1))/2}%
  }

  % The inner function
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{square}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1*#1}%
  }

  % Compute the sum of another function
  % Does not work...
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{manual_sum}{1}{%
    %Parameter should be integral
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\cnt{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ret{0}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\cnt} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ret{\ret + sum(\i)}
    }
    \pgfmathparse{\ret}
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      % Expected
      \addplot[samples at={1,...,10}] {explicit_sum(x)};

      % Does not work
      \addplot[samples at={1,...,10}] {manual_sum(x)};
    \end{axis}    
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you trying to accumulate a function value ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to accumulate a function for 1,...,#1

Comment: Well I think the `\pgfmathparse` needs to be inside the `\foreach` when I switch that the plot returns a straight line, I think the remaining issue is the same as found in [Summation of a list of numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179547/).

Answer (score 4):

If it is allowed to produce an "invisible" table to define the x values and then make the calculations in another column, then you could do the following.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    % Explicit formula
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{explicit_sum}{1}{%
        \pgfmathparse{(#1*(#1-1))/2}%
    }
    \pgfplotstableset{
        % define how the 'x' column shall be filled
        % (in this case just with integers counting from 1)
        create on use/x/.style={
            create col/set list={1,...,100}
        },
        % -----
        % now you can either create here a column with your function ...
        create on use/fx/.style={
            create col/expr={(\thisrow{x})^2}
        },
        % ... and then accumulate the values here ...
        create on use/sum/.style={
            create col/expr accum={
                \pgfmathaccuma + \thisrow{fx}
            }{0},       % <-- start with `0'
        },
        % -----
        % ... or you accumulate directly with the function
        create on use/sum2/.style={
            create col/expr accum={
                \pgfmathaccuma + (\thisrow{x})^2
            }{0},       % <-- start with `0'
        },
        % -----
    }
    % here you create a new table using the columns you need and
    % with the first mandatory argument you specify the number of elements
    % the table should have
    % (so either `sum2' is redundant or (`fx' and `sum') are redundant)
    \pgfplotstablenew[
        columns={x,fx,sum,sum2},
    ]{10}{\loadedtable}
\begin{document}
%    % maybe it is useful to typeset the table for debugging purposes
%    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
%        columns={x,fx,sum,sum2},
%    ]{\loadedtable}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % added for debugging purposes or here to quicker check,
            % it one gets the desired output
            nodes near coords,
        ]
        % Expected
        \addplot+[samples at={1,...,10}] {explicit_sum(x)};

        % when the table is created, you can use the columns here
        \addplot table [x=x,y=sum] {\loadedtable};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 3):

TL; DR, the function declaration should be

```
  \pgfmathdeclarefunction{manual_sum}{1}{%
    \pgfmathfloattoint{#1}\let\cnt\pgfmathresult%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ret{0}%
    \foreach\i in{1,...,\cnt}{%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\ret{\ret+\i}         % summing integer itself
     %\pgfmathsetmacro\ret{\ret+square(\i)} % general case
      \xdef\ret{\ret}%
    }%
    \pgfmathparse{\ret}%
  }
```

---

There are two problems in your code:

- First, `\foreach` introduces nested grouping and `\ret` is trapped in the group.
- Second, since [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots) activates FPU, the `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\cnt{#1}` will make `\cnt` be `1`.

  - (This is in fact the **flag** of `#1` in the FPU representation.)
  - (**flag** `1` stands for positive number.)

---

To come over the first obstacle, I usually use `\xdef` to smuggle the value. It is also worth noting that [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots) introduces `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, which is literally an ungrouped version of `\foreach`.

For the second obstacle, one needs to check the manual carefully and finds that `\pgfmathfloattoint{#1}\let\cnt\pgfmathresult` is the correct way to do the job.

---

this will bring you a curve that is different from the `explicit_sum`, and then you will realize that `#1*(#1-1)/2` is not the correct formula.

Comment: +1  Nice one. This will be "magic" for me forever I think, but luckily there are people like you who know stuff like that.  If I see it correct you are doing $\sum_i x_i$, right, but the question was: "Sum *a function*". Since OP declared the function `square` I think this was an example for *a function*. Could you modify your answer accordingly. (At least *this* I would be able to ;)) (OP himself wrote `sum(\i)` which most probably was an error, because `\ret` stores the sum, right?

Comment: @StefanPinnow Yes it is $\sum_i x_i$, indeed. I ignored `square()` because `explicit_sum()` is defined to be triangle numbers. (It would have been `#1*(#1+1)*(2*#1-1)/6` for summing squares.) Nonetheless I added a commented line for summing squares. And right, `\ret` stores the sum. (I guess `\ret` stands for `return`.)