# Plotting Lagrange interpolation polynomial

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am writing a code that plots the Lagrange polynomial of a given function. I have all the necessary data, but I can't find a way to plot

```
$P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n (f(a_i) \prod_{j\neq i,j=0}^n \frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j} )$
```

Or

[image]

Note that I don't want to use pgfplots, since I already know how to do it this way. Using only tikz I find difficult to declare the function to plot. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: This looks like a huge expression. I'd use Lua or something-else to compute the coordinates, also avoid possible floating point error etc.

Comment: There's [How to use a summation in a tikz plot - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402730/how-to-use-a-summation-in-a-tikz-plot) / [tikz pgf - Visualizing a function defined through a summation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526585/visualizing-a-function-defined-through-a-summation) . For the product I'm not too sure